# How to get web session on Spring AOP

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I have a question for using Spring AspectJ. I want to create an audit log when the user does something and get user information from web session to create the audit log.
Can anyone provide examples of how to do this?

Answer (score 6):

Spring MVC's `DispatcherServlet` stores request in a thread-local variable (if you don't use Spring MVC, you may declare `RequestContextListener` in `web.xml` to do the same thing). This variable can be accessed via [`RequestContextHolder`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.html):

```
HttpSession s = (HttpSession) RequestContextHolder
                    .currentRequestAttributes()
                    .resolveReference(RequestAttributes.REFERENCE_SESSION);
```